# CakePHP ACL: Optional ACO Node (allow by default)

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, acl

I'm making a CakePHP app using a modified version of database ACL.

In order to avoid having to create ACO nodes for every single controller, I would like to establish a system whereby users are allowed access to a page *unless otherwise denied*. This means that I don't want to create ACO nodes for controllers unless absolutely necessary.

Normally, if I fail to create an ACO node, when my `isAuthorised()` function performs `$this->Acl->check`, I get an error such as this...

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: Array
(
    [model] => Role
    [foreign_key] => 1
)
```

I think a feasible solution would be to check if the ACO node exists before performing a `$this->Acl->check` command. If it doesn't exist, then it would be possible to stop it from checking permissions.

Is there a way to check out if an ACO node exists, based on the output of `$this->Auth->action()` (which outputs something like `controllers/Members/Edit`)?

My Auth ActionPath is set to 'controllers'.

Or maybe there is a better way of going about it?

I hope I have phrased my question adequately, I will ensure to clarify if not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by making an edit to the core ACL.php file, there was no normal solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this](http://api.cakephp.org/class/acl-node#method-AclNodenode) to check if the Aco exists.

```
if($this->Acl->Aco->node('controllers/Members/Edit')) {
    debug('Aco exists!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ACL component you must have ARO and ACO trees. Otherwise there is no sense to use that component.

I would suggest you to create a super-user for all users, allow him to access all ACO nodes, but deny specific ACO nodes. So, all users would inherit the permissions from that abstract super-user. I guess you have studied [Simple Acl controlled Application tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application), haven't you?

Another option would be to use Auth component and write your own permissions handling component. There are many tutorials how to build admin panel.